# Aplicar filtro em apenas parte da imagem

Tags: html, css, filtro

Tenho uma imagem no background do meu site e gostaria de aplicar o filtro `brightness` em toda a imagem com exceção de uma parte como mostra na imagem:

[image: imagem]

Alguma dica de como fazer isso? Já tentei a `tag` `map`, porém ela serve apenas para marcar setores da imagem, sem a possibilidade de alterar o *style*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque não adicionar duas `<div>` com opacidade sobre a imagem?

```html
<style>
div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}
#imagem{
  background-image: url('http://assets.dornob.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/dining-room-desk-table.jpg');
}
.transparencia{
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.quadro1{
  top:0px;
  height:60px;
}
.quadro2{
  top:140px;
  height:160px;
}
</style>

<div id="imagem" />
<div class="transparencia quadro1" ></div>
<div class="transparencia quadro2"></div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolvermos esse problema, e utilizando o filtro `brightness`, podemos utilizar a propriedade [clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp):

> A propriedade clip permite que você especifique um retângulo para
>   cortar um elemento absolutamente posicionado. O retângulo é
>   especificado como quatro coordenadas, tudo a partir do canto superior
>   esquerdo do elemento a ser cortado.

Como não li direito a pergunta, fiz o inverso que pediu, ou seja, a faixa ter filtro `brightness`:

```css
.brightness div{ 
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;

} 

#filter img{
-webkit-filter:brightness(200%);
        filter:brightness(200%);
  
}
#filter{ 
  position:absolute;
  clip: rect(30px, auto, 90px, auto); 
/*   (top, right, bottom, left) */
}
```

```html
<div class="brightness">
  <div id="original">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/laptop-na-mesa-do-escritorio_426-19315253.jpg">    
  </div>
  <div id="filter">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/laptop-na-mesa-do-escritorio_426-19315253.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ai fiz o que você quer fazer:

```css
.brightness div{ 
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
} 

#noFilter{ 
  position:absolute;
  clip: rect(30px, auto, 90px, auto); 
/*   (top, right, bottom, left) */
}

#original img{
-webkit-filter:brightness(200%);
        filter:brightness(200%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="brightness">
  <div id="original">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/laptop-na-mesa-do-escritorio_426-19315253.jpg">    
  </div>
  <div id="noFilter">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/laptop-na-mesa-do-escritorio_426-19315253.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```